# If `pipenv install` update both `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, why is there the need to regenerate lock with `pipenv lock`?

Tags: pipenv

According to the [documentation](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/#basic-commands-and-concepts):

```
pipenv install foo==0.x
```

will install `foo` with the specified version and update both `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`.

If the `foo` has been written into both files, then what is the need for `pipenv lock` command?

The document said it:

> Regenarate `Pipfile.lock` and updates the dependencies inside it.

Under what situation do we need to call the `pipenv lock` command?

Thanks if you could clarify my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, it can be used to update all your dependencies before entering production.

`pipenv lock` is used to create a `Pipfile.lock`, which declares all dependencies (and sub-dependencies) of your project, their latest available versions, and the current hashes for the downloaded files. This ensures repeatable, and most importantly deterministic, builds.

You can use `pipenv lock` to compile your dependencies on your development environment and deploy the compiled `Pipfile.lock` to all of your production environments for reproducible builds.